Decode repeated message in Nanopb one item at a time
Let's say, I have a nanopb message like:
syntax = "proto3";

message Row
{
  uint32 startAddress = 1;
  bytes data = 2;
}

message File
{
  repeated Row row = 1;
}

I want to decode a File with multiple rows, but row by row. This way I don't have to store all rows in RAM a second time. (Encoded + Decoded)
How do I achieve this?
So I need a loop, decoding just one row and storing the position of stream. After I did my calculation with the decoded row, the next row can be decoded. So in pseudo code:
void decode_File(const std::uint8_t* data, std::size_t length)
{
  Row row;
  pb_istream_t istream = pb_istream_from_buffer(data, length);
  while (pb_decode(&istream, Row_fields, &row))
  {
    DoingStuffWithRow(row);
  }
}


There are two approaches you could take:

Configure a field callback, and handle the data in the callback function.
Iterate over the message in your own code, and decode it piece-by-piece.

Your example is closer to the second approach.
To implement it, you need to understand the protobuf encoding. Nanopb provides pb_decode_tag() function that you can then use to iterate over the message fields while decoding them from a stream.
Note that the stream itself also doesn't have to come from a memory buffer, but can use callbacks. Processing the data immediately as it comes from a communication interface can further cut down RAM requirements.
